# Update DATETIME column where said DATETIME < current DATETIME

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've got an ASP.NET 4.0 C# web application that allows multiple users to update rows in the SQL Server DB at the same time. I'm trying to come up with a quick system that will stop USER1 from updating a row that USER2 updated since USER1's last page refresh.

The problem I'm having is that my web application always updates the row, even when I think it shouldn't. But when I manually run the query it only updates when I think it should.

This is my SQL query in C#:

```
SQLString = "update statuses set stat = '" + UpdaterDD.SelectedValue +
            "', tester = '" + Session["Username"].ToString() +
            "', timestamp_m = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") +
            "' where id IN (" + IDs + ") and timestamp_m < '" + PageLoadTime + "';";
```

And here's a 'real world' example:

```
SQLString = "update statuses set stat = 'PASS', tester = 'tester007',
             timestamp_m = '2013-01-23 14:20:07.221' where id IN (122645) and
             timestamp_m < '2013-01-23 14:20:06.164';"
```

My idea was that this will only update if no other user has changed this row since the user last loaded the page. I have formatted `PageLoadTime` to the same formatting as my SQL Server DB, as you can see with `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`, but something still isn't right.

Does anyone know why I get two different results? Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: why don't you have 2 DateTime columns one for the original inserted record and the other for the updated capturing who inserted the original and add another userUpdatedBy Column this way you don't have to mess around with changing one date plus from and auditing standpoint you're approach is not correct...

Comment: why are you allowing multiple users to update the same record.. can you implement some record / row locking in your current design..? also you may find it to be more beneficial to create Parameterized queries for the update statement it's cleaner and easier to do that way

Comment: Where is `PageLoadTime` getting set? Have you debugged and checked what the value is?

Comment: Typically people use a `ROWVERSION` column to control concurrent updates - then it doesn't rely on consistency between what your web server thinks the page load time was and when the row was last modified. This approach does not seem very scalable or safe at all...

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I apologize for not reading that before posting, and thank you.
@DJKRAZE: I'm definitely going to look into Parameterized queries. My current design would not accommodate record/row locking as you suggest, though that just means I probably need to scrap the design.
@DaveZych: `PageLoadTime` is set on `Page_Load` like so: `PageLoadTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");`.

Comment: @DaveZych: Yes, I have checked in debug, and the value appears to be correct and matches the format of my SQL DATETIME column. I've gone as far as adding a break on the `ExecuteNonQuery()` line, grabbed the actual sql string from the debugger, run it manually against the DB before resuming. When I run it manually, it updates when it should, but when I let my app resume, it updates the row no matter what.

Comment: My take is that the delay from you manually grabbing the sql string and executing it instead of letting it run naturally is why it is "working as expected." I'd also paramterize the dates so you don't have to worry about the date/time string being in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think the problem is that the page load time is not being set correctly, or is being set immediately before the DB call. For debugging, you may try hardcoding values into it that you know will allow or disallow the insert.

Here's a parameterized version of what you have. I also am letting the DB server set the timestamp to its current time instead of passing a value. If your DB server and your Web server may not have their time of day in synch, then set it yourself.

Using parameterization, you don't have to worry about whether the date/time format is correct or not. I don't know what the DB types are of stat, tester, and timestamp_m so adding the parameter DB type may need adjusting.

```
string sql = "update statuses set stat = @stat, tester = @tester" +
        ", timestamp_m = getdate()" +
        " where id IN (" + IDs + ") and timestamp_m < @pageLoadTime";

SQLConnection conn = getMeASqlConnection();

SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand(sql, conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@stat", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UpdaterDD.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tester", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["Username"].ToString();
// Here, pageLoadTime is a DateTime object, not a string
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pageLoadTime", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = pageLoadTime;
```

Comment: Well, switching over to parameterized queries hasn't fixed my problem on its own. I've added a label on the page to display the value of `PageLoadTime`. I loaded the page at 10:40am (verified by the lable), and then manually set `timestamp_m` in the DB for 10:44am and attempted to update. It did not let me update until 10:44am, so clearly part of this is working. But it still does not work when USER1 loads the page at 10:40am, USER2 updates at 10:44am, USER1 (without reloading, so his `PageLoadTime` is still 10:40) can immediately update even though 10:44 < 10:40 is not true.

Comment: Are you sure PageLoadTime isn't being updated when USER1 submits the update? Do you check for !IsPostBack before updating PageLoadTime?

Comment: You are completely correct. I had moved `PageLoadTime` inside of my `if (!IsPostBack)` block, but that doesn't do any good if I also initialized the dang thing right before that. I removed `PageLoadTime` and replaced it with a session variable that is only updated if `IsPostBack` is false. Problem solved.